# C# How to convert between Float and Decimal?

Tags: c#, floating-point, decimal, converters

I want to use a NumberUpDownBox to get and set a float value.
All I Know is that this doesn't work:

```
DecimalConverter dec = new DecimalConverter();
((NumericUpDown)_control).Value = (Decimal)dec.ConvertFrom((float)value);
```

I am finding little documentation on how to do this...

Comment: casting would work just fine: `decimal value = (decimal)floatValue;`

Comment: I think that was the first thing I tried. Now I forget. I'll get back to you on that.

Comment: Like others have said, use the explicit conversions of C#, that is `x = (decimal)y;` and `y = (float)x;`. The old non-generic [`System.ComponentModel.DecimalConverter` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.decimalconverter.aspx) has a documentation saying _This converter can only convert a decimal object to and from a string._ That is mostly useless (better handled by the methods of `decimal` itself), especially in your use.

Comment: Does "Convert.ToDecimal(f)" and "Convert.ToSingle(d)"  work better than "decimal d = new decimal(a)"? I really want to be sure I'm giving BA to the BA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is just to cast:

```
float a = 2.3F;
decimal d = (decimal)a;
```

Alternatively you could use a `decimal` constructor:

```
decimal d = new decimal(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`Convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Convert(v=vs.110).aspx) class has static methods for converting between most primitive types.

To convert from `float` to `decimal` you can use [`Convert.ToDecimal()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he38a8ca(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
float f = 1.0f;
decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(f);
```

To go the other way you can use [`Convert.ToSingle()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e99y3aec(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
decimal d = 1.0m;
float f = Convert.ToSingle(d);
```